# how to show date filter by next 5 months via expose filter in drupal?

Tags: views

I have a content type with date fields . For date I am using date module. I have created a views in drupal 7 and using exposed filter. I need to show filter my data via month , Means I need to show months(next 5 months including current) in dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

What you're wanting is *Grouped Filters*. It will let you set pre-defined discrete filters for your date.

Under the Views UI for your exposed data filter set **Filter type to expose** to *Grouped Filters*. You can set your arbitrary **label**, set your **operator** to *is between*, and **Value type** to *An offset from the current time...* in the date fields, you can use a relative PHP [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) format to specify a filter between the current date ("now") and 5 months into the future ("+5 month").

Comment: I need to may, june, july, aug, sep in label.

Comment: Grouped Filters will let you add fixed date ranges in addition to relative dates.